# CakePhp adding label to select formhelper

Tags: php, cakephp

I would like to add a label to my `select` form helper however I am not quite sure how to do this in cake v2+.

This is my current code which does not work:

```
echo $this->Form->select('format_id', $formats, array('label'=>'Format:'));
```

Comment: If your are going to downvote, please explain how I can improve the question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do this:

```
 echo $this->Form->label('Format');
 echo $this->Form->select('format_id', $formats, array());
```

or

```
 echo $this->Form->input('format_id', array('label'=>'Format', 'type'=>'select', 'options'=>$formats));
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer, it is because you need to use `Form->input` like so...

```
echo $this->Form->input('format_id', array('label'=>'Format: ', 'type'=>'select', 'options'=>$formats));
```